# Latex AMS align / Align multiple "=", too much space

Tags: latex

I'd like to align some equations in Latex using the AMS packages. Each equation has two equal signs that need to be aligned. So something in the line of

```
A = B = C
D = E = F
```

I've tried using the align-environment like this

```
\begin{align}
A &= B &= C \\
D &= E &= F
\end{align}
```

This works in principle (it aligns), however it adds ridiculously large spaces before the second equal sign in each line.
But I just want the line to runs as if there was no additional alignment tab. Only when I replace for example "B" by "BBB" I want the equal sign before "F" to shift to right the exact amount of space.

Could anyone help me out on that one? It's kind of driving me crazy since I don't get the idea of that strange behavior and I just can't find any solution. Maybe alignat could help, but I don't really get how that environment works or in how it differs from normal align.

Cheers,
Oliver

Comment: You might want to consider posting this on the TeX Stack Exhange site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks man, this site looks great. I'm just puzzled how I never came across it before..
I've posted my question there in case people are interested: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6572/ams-align-align-multiple--too-much-space

Comment: Better fit for TeX.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should work:

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
  A &= B & &=  C \\
  D &= E & &=  F
\end{alignat}
```

From ams guide:

> A variant environment alignat allows
>   the horizontal space between equations
>   to be explicitly specified. This
>   environment takes one argument, the
>   number of “equation columns”: count
>   the maximum number of &s in any row,
>   add 1 and divide by 2.

Its not exactly intended for what you are trying to do, but since align insists on adding space... 
The idea behind align is:

```
l&=r   &   l&=r \\
l&=r   &   l&=r
```

One '&' per function, and a '&' between functions.

I would hope there is a better solution though.

Comment: \begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{rcl}
      A    =& BB &= CCC \\
      DDDD =& FFFFF &= GGGGGG
    \end{array}
  \end{equation}

Answer (score 4):

(6½ to 8 years later)

What about using `array` with a custom separator?

```
\begin{array}{r@{\ }c@{\ }l}
A &= B &= C \\
D &= E &= F
\end{array}
```

Comment: Finally, the answer. Please post it here as well https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6572/ams-align-align-multiple--too-much-space

Comment: Good idea! Done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644013/157414

Answer (score -5):

What about the below? They produce aligned "=" signs for me...

```
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
 A  &  =  &  B  &  =  &  C  \\
 D  &  =  &  E  &  =  &  F  \\
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{lllll}
 A  &  =  &  BBB  &  =  &  C  \\
 D  &  =  &  E  &  =  &  F  \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: You can't use tabular in math mode, so this isn't a solution.

Comment: What about `\begin{array}...\end{array}` though?

Comment: I use array and override the column separator: \begin{array}{l@{\ =\ }l@{\ =\ }l}.  That way I don't have to type the = on all the lines.